# Удаление из строки всех символов кроме цифр и символа + вначале?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

только такие варианты подходят вида 
+2992924004

не подходят

++39393

++++0202020

3030030+39339

2929+02002+++292929

02020++++++++++

Делаю вот так:

```
value.replace(/[^+\d]/g, '').replace(/(\d)\++/g, '$1')
```

но при этом не удаляется плюс, если два вподряд `++`, а так такой вариант мне подходит.

Comment: например: `/^\+\d+$/`

Comment: Ответ ниже, если плюс в начале обязателен - прибавьте его после удаления всех, нет смысла усложнять выражения для такой тривиальной задачи.

Comment: Если вы уже что-либо пробовали, добавьте в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: c /^\+\d+$/ и не цфры попадают

а нужны ток цифры и плюс в самом начале

Comment: Кончено, это вам не подходит. Приведите ваш код, чтобы понять, что именно вы делаете, в чём проблема и как вам лучше помочь.

Comment: делаю вот так

value.replace(/[^+\d]/g, '').replace(/(\d)\++/g, '$1')

но при этом не удаляется плюс, если два вподряд ++

а так такой вариант мне подходит

Comment: Попробуйте `value.replace(/^(\+)|\D+/g, "$1")`

Comment: `'+'+value.replace(/\D+/g, '')`

Comment: @werty, да, я не так понял что нужно

Answer (score 1):

```js
function clean(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?!^\+|\d)./g, "")
}

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  document.querySelector('output').textContent = clean(e.target.value)
})
```

```css
input { width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

```html
<input><output></output>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать

```
.replace(/^(\+)|\D+/g, "$1")
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/RTVbc3/1).

- `^` - начало строки
- `(\+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: плюс
- `|` - или
- `\D+` - один и более знаков, отлчных от цифры.

Если была найдена подмаска №1, её текст вставляется обратно с помощью `$1`, т.е. если плюса в начале строки не было, его там и не будет.

```js
var strs = ['+2992924004', '++39393', '++++0202020', '3030030+39339', '2929+02002+++292929', '02020++++++++++'];
for (var value of strs) {
  console.log(value, "=>", value.replace(/^(\+)|\D+/g, "$1"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let number_str = "+38 (099) 999-99-99";

function clear_number(number)
{
  let new_number = number.replace(/[\D]/g,"");
  if(new_number.length != 0) new_number = "+" + new_number;
  return new_number;
}

alert(clear_number(number_str));
```

Comment: `/[\D+()-\s]/g` = `/\D/g`.

Comment: Благодарю, недоглядел...

Comment: в первом варианте плюс тоже убирается если вначале

"+djjd888w".replace(/[\D]/g,"");

нужно оставлять ток плюс вначале один . и цифры

Comment: Изменил. Если плюса в начале нет - он добивится.

Comment: тогда если набрать символ любой, то плюс будет добавляться всегда

у меня форматтер инпута
если набирать символ, то ничего не должно выводить, а будет возвращаться плюс, так как принудительно ставим его вначало

Comment: @werty Т.е. если плюса не было, добавлять не надо?

Comment: да, так. еще доп проверка

Comment: @werty, всё. Регулярное выражение удалит всё, если нет цифр, и, если ничего не осталось, то и плюс не добавится.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "+38 (099) 999-99-99";
alert(str.replace(/ |\-|\)|\(/g,""));
```